# Wpf + Caliburn Micro: Binding Textbox to a custom object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, caliburn.micro

I use Wpf 4.5 and Caliburn Micro 2.0.2.

I want to bind a Textbox to a property of view model. The property (called ResultData) is an object from class TextXmlData. The class is a automatically generated class from a xsd. I use Microsoft Xsd.exe to make it.

This is the view model

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IHaveDisplayName
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    private TestXmlData _resultData;
    public TestXmlData ResultData
    {
        get { return _resultData; }
        set
        {
            _resultData = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _resultData);
        }
    }

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Shell Window";
    }

    public void CreateObject()
    {
        String xmlData = "<TestXmlData><Id>88</Id><Name>What a name</Name></TestXmlData>";
        if (ResultData == null) { ResultData = new TestXmlData(); }
        XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ResultData.GetType());
        ResultData = (TestXmlData)oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlData)); 
        // at this point the debugger shows that the ResultData is correctly filled, 
        // the Name is definitely not empty
    }
}
```

and this is the view

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMWpfXmlSerializer2Ways.Views.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">
    <StackPanel Width="200"
                Height="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="CreateObject"
                Width="190"
                Content="Create Object from XML" />
        <TextBox Width="190"
                 DataContext="{Binding ResultData}"
                 Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the TextBox shows always empty!

I have tried also with Text="{Binding ResultData.Name}", but the TextBox still shows empty.

Anyone can help and show me what is wrong with my code above?
Please feel free to modify the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your `ResultData ` is null/Empty ?

Comment: What are the properties in TestXmlData

Comment: @AbinMathew my ResultData in ViewModel has correct content, so it is not empty and also not null.

Comment: @mvermef in TestXmlData there are only 2 properties: Id and Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I read your comments, hints, suggestions and my code again and again, I find out the cause of the problem incidentally. And it is my own mistake (yes, my stupid mistake)

I have used ***the backing field _resultData*** on NotifyOfPropertyChange instead of ***the property name ResultData***! (please see in the view model the setter of property ResultData)

Thank you very much to you all!

Comment: Using the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute instead of a member expression can prevent this sort of mistake. You can also create a code snippet for change-notifying properties, if there isn't one already in Visual Studio. EDIT: To clarify, your `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method's signature would be `NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`, and you just call it without arguments from within your properties' setters. The compiler will insert the property names as strings for you.

Comment: 2.02 should already have that... NotifyPropertyChange() should work with out the lambda

Answer (score 2):

ResultData is a property of ViewModel. So, you need to set ViewModel as DataContext at some higher level, then you can use it's property as binding source at some lower level.

To run your sample, I made some changes and ran like below :

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbName" DataContext="{Binding ResultData}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

///

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
        ShellViewModel vm = new ShellViewModel();
        vm.CreateObject();

        this.DataContext = vm;
    } 
    ...
```

///

```
public class ShellViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        private TestXmlData _resultData;
        public TestXmlData ResultData
        {
            get { return _resultData; }
            set
            {
                _resultData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ResultData");
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "Shell Window";
        }

        public void CreateObject()
        {
            String xmlData = "<TestXmlData><Id>88</Id><Name>What a name</Name></TestXmlData>";
            if (ResultData == null) { ResultData = new TestXmlData(); }
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ResultData.GetType());
            ResultData = (TestXmlData)oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlData));
            // at this point the debugger shows that the ResultData is correctly filled, 
            // the Name is definitely not empty
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: The command of your view and my view (xaml) has almost no difference except the x:Name, which in my case can be ignored. And your suggestion uses the plain WPF, but I use Caliburn Micro Framework, so I don't need explicitly to declare PropertyChanged, etc. I appreciate your effort to help.

Comment: Have you read my answer ? Either set DataContext at root to ShellViewModel, or change your DataContext of your TextBox to DataContext="{Binding  myShellViewModel.ResultData}" where myShellViewModel is VM instance.

Comment: sure, I have read your answer. Changing DataContext of my TextBox and I get: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ShellViewModel' property not found on 'object' ''ShellViewModel' (HashCode=32957278)'. I don't need to change DataContext of root because Caliburn Micro Framework works with Naming Convention thus the framework bind automatically ShellView.xaml and ShellViewModel.cs

Comment: @AnjumSKhan while correct in the mvvm approach you missed the whole point of the question... He is using Caliburn.Micro, which does all of this behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have debugging enabled with Caliburn.MIcro?  This would be done from your BootStrapper.  This will tell us whether or not your view and viewmodel are bound correctly.

usually placed into the CTOR of the bootstrapper
LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);

Since you are using a UserControl for your shellview I would like to see your BootStrapper.

I suspect a few things are incorrect or namespaces aren't set correctly, which would lead to binding errors.

Comment: The bootstrapper is ok, because if I bind a TextBox to a property with has value as String (public String SomeProperty) it works.